# how to make 2 controls share the same listbox

Tags: wpf, user-controls, listbox, share, items

Is it possible to have a listbox displaying its items with a control template to change their look in the listbox and also have a canvas displaying the listboxItems with another look?

To be more accurate,

I have a UserControl named InfoControl and another named DesignerControl with the same DataContext: a DesignerVM which contains an ObservableCollection of CurveVM.

In my InfoControl, I have a listbox with its items binded to the OC and shown as stackpanels using a template.

Now I want to display my items in the DesignerControl (canvas) but with another look.

Should i have to create another listbox and synchronize it with the first one or is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: don't share the listbox, but databind the two listboxes to the same datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two controls shouldn't share a listbox. Instead, make two separate listboxes and bind them to the same ItemsSource or DataContext. [Use a DataTemplateSelector](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector) to control which template is used.

Edit: And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: yeah that's what i was starting to do.
I found my mistake when you answered :)

And thx for the quick answer, it's nice to see open-minded people helpin' newbies like me, and not just trollin' 4 fun